# Suggestions for Detailed Application Permissions Architecture

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, permissions

I've got an application that needs an overhaul of it's permissioning system.

This application has 2 types of "entities" that need securing:

- Users
- Companies

Users are simple, they just have roles that give them access to areas within the application, no data will change.

Companies can be one of 3 types - administrative (currently just the "master" company that owns the product), partners (resellers of the product) and standard (people just using the product).

The product also has the concept of "Groups" of companies, because resellers can sell the product under different names, but need to be able to see all the data at once. Therefore, each company always belongs to a group, and each group, in turn, is owned by a company.

When querying data, I have a few requirements:

- If a user belonging to reseller company A queries the data, all the companies in all the groups that reseller owns need to show up
- If a user belonging to standard company B queries the data, they should only see their info
- If a user belonging to administrative company C queries the data, they should see everything
- Finally, the actual data that's shown needs to be filtered by company type - administrative companies see more data than resellers, who see more info than standard companies

Now, the current system actually does most of this, but it's a lot of:

```
List<int> groups;
if(CompanyType == CompanyType.Reseller){
  groups = [some list of groups]
}else{
  ....
}
```

Which is rather ugly and error-prone.

We're using SubSonic, WCF (the whole system is designed with a REST interface), PostSharp, and C#, so you know the tools available.

Can anyone suggest a nice way to implement permissions with this level of detail (row and column, essentially) at the framework level to ensure the restrictions are set appropriately and automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar problem. Basically, my pseudo algorithm was :

```
IEnumerable<MyData> allDatas = DataAccessLayer.GetDatas();
IEnumerable<MyData> filteredDatas = RuleEngine.Filter(allDatas);
// filteredDatas contains only the datas that the user is authorized to view
```

First I get for example all the products from the database. Then I filter them with the business rules. You will probably have to add some parameters to RuleEngine.Filter : the current user, and maybe some contextual informations.

In order to get twenty products, you can write some code like this one :

```
IDataReader reader = GetReader();
var products = new List<Product>();
while(reader.Read() && products.Count < 20)
{
    var product = BuildProduct(reader);
    if(RuleEngine.Filter(new Product[] { product }).Any())
        products.Add(product);
}
```

Comment: What kind of performance hits does that introduce though? If I have a table with 100,000 records, I want to filter that at the database level if possible...

Comment: Do you have a scenario where you will have to load 100,000 records ? You will probably, for example for your products, filter them by categories and some other criterias.

Comment: A lot of time it's just a top-20 filter, so I have a query that limits it there...otherwise I have to query top-X, and hope that the filter doesn't return less than 20 :)

Comment: the first line is scary IEnumerable<MyData> allDatas = DataAccessLayer.GetDatas();